How to get the immediate value after each iteration?
Does pyomo support to pass a function to access model value each iteration? I want to check the solution every 50 iter, how can I achieve this?

I don't think that is possible. Of course, you can stop after n iterations and repeat this.

Hi Erwin, do you know if pyomo supports the callback function just like JUMP JUMP_callback

I believe this is only possible with the persistent solvers. See the Pyomo documentation.
